# Any way to find more detail about WARNING: ID3D10Buffer::SetPrivateData: Existing private data of same name with different size found!

Tags: directx, directx-10

I'm encountering this error when I'm running my DirectX10 program in debug mode:

D3D10: WARNING: ID3D10Buffer::SetPrivateData: Existing private data of same name with different size found! [ STATE_SETTING WARNING #55: SETPRIVATEDATA_CHANGINGPARAMS ]

I'm trying to make the project highly OOP as a learning exercise, so there's a chance that this may be occurring, but is there a way to get some more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What other data are you looking for or interested in?

The warning is pretty clear about what is going on, but if you want to hunt down a bit more data, there may be a few things to try.

Try calling `ID3D10Buffer::GetPrivateData` with the same name or do some other check to see if there is data with that name already, and if so, what the contents are. Print your results to a file, output window, or console. This may be combined with breakpoints to see where the duplicate is occurring (break when there's already data).

You *may* (not positive) be able to set the D3D runtimes to debug mode and to break on warnings (not sure if it can do warnings or just errors). Debug your app in VS or your preferred debugger, and when the warning is shown, it will break and you can look at the parameters.

Go through your code and track down all calls to `ID3D10Buffer::SetPrivateData` and look to see if there are any obvious duplicates. If there are, work up the program flow and see why and what you can do about them (this may work best after you use one of the former methods to know where to start).

How are your data names set up, and what is the buffer used for? Examining one or both may lead you to a conflict somewhere.

You may also try unicorns, they've been known to help with this kind of problem.

Comment: Unicorns - cute. I was able to debug it without anything else, but I'll try that next time.

Comment: Seems to be the time of year for them again, so I figured I might as well throw them in the answer. :P

Answer (score 2):

It appears this warning is raised by D3DX10CreateSprite, which is internally called by font->DrawText
You can ignore this warning, seems to be a bug in the Ms code :)

Direct3D11 doesn't have built-in text rendering anymore, so you won't encounter it in the future.

Comment: commenting out `mFont->DrawText(0, mFrameStats.c_str(), -1, &R, DT_NOCLIP, BLACK);` made the error go away, which is fine by me since i didnt need it right now.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a D3D11 warning, you could always turn it off using `ID3D11InfoQueue`:

```cpp
D3D11_MESSAGE_ID hide [] = {
    D3D11_MESSAGE_ID_SETPRIVATEDATA_CHANGINGPARAMS,
    // Add more message IDs here as needed
};

D3D11_INFO_QUEUE_FILTER filter;
memset(&filter, 0, sizeof(filter));
filter.DenyList.NumIDs  = _countof(hide);
filter.DenyList.pIDList = hide;
d3dInfoQueue->AddStorageFilterEntries(&filter);
```

See [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/11/30/direct3d-sdk-debug-layer-tricks.aspx) for more. I found your question while googling for the answer and had to search a bit more to find the above snippet, hopefully this will help someone :)